# Un JavaScript por vista en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando que no todos los JavaScripts se usen en todos los HTMLs.

Lo primero que hice fue eliminar el require_tree.

Entonces usé esta línea en mi vista

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "fiscal", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
```

y me salió este error:

> Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
>   Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( judicial.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server.

Hice lo que indica el error e instale algo llamado yarn. Luego corrí este código en consola:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile</code><br>
```

y me salió esto:

```
yarn install v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
Done in 0.12s.
```

Pero sigue siendo el mismo error. Por favor, necesito saber dónde está el error o una alternativa.

Comment: Hola, este sitio es en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo que te indica el mismo error del pantallazo que pusiste, agregar

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( judicial.js )
```

en tu archivo `config/initializers/assets.rb` y luego reiniciar.

Solo un punto aparte, ¿por que razón no quieres cargar el mismo javascript en tus páginas? En general la razón de que esto sea así es para cargar un único archivo cuando se cargue la página y por tanto hacer menos peticiones al servidor de tu página. Obviamente se puede romper dicha regla siempre cuando sea estrictamente necesario, lo cual la gran mayoría de las veces no lo es.